# Stored Procedure ahowing 'lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction in mysql stored procedure' error?How to handel it?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, mariasql

Hello guys i am trying to validate otp verification manually.for that i have written this stored procedure .When i started this code was working fine but after some time its start giving error.It was taking too long time to execute approx 50sec and after that it was giving the error lock wait timeout.So can anyone tell me why its giving such error and how to resolve it?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxx`@`xxxx` PROCEDURE `new_mobile_authentication`(
    IN in_macID VARCHAR(500),IN in_otp INT(5),OUT in_msg VARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN
    DECLARE userCount INT(10);
    DECLARE emailID VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE mobileNumber BIGINT(11);
    DECLARE checkmatched INT(5);

    DELETE FROM mob_user WHERE NOW()>end_time;
    SELECT COUNT(*),email,mobile,otp into userCount,emailID,mobileNumber,checkmatched FROM  mob_user WHERE  mac_id=in_macID ;
    SET @checkEmailPresent=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table A WHERE email_id=emailID);

    IF(userCount!=0 AND @checkEmailPresent!=0)THEN
      IF(checkmatched=in_otp)THEN

        UPDATE table A SET auth='YES',mac_id=in_macID,mobile_num=mobileNumber WHERE email=emailID;
        SET @affRow=(SELECT ROW_COUNT());
        DELETE FROM mob_user WHERE mac_id=in_macID;
        SELECT @affRow AS affRow,email FROM table A WHERE mac_id=in_macID;
      ELSE
        SELECT 'invalid otp' INTO in_msg;
      END IF;

    ELSEIF(userCount!=0 AND @checkEmailPresent=0)THEN
      IF(checkmatched=in_otp)THEN

        INSERT INTO table A(email,mobile_num,mac_id) VALUE (emailID,mobileNumber,in_macID,); 
        SET @affRow=(SELECT ROW_COUNT());
        DELETE FROM mob_user WHERE mac_id=in_macID;
        SELECT  @affRow AS affRow,email FROM table A WHERE mac_id=in_macID;
      ELSE
        SELECT 'invalid otp' INTO in_msg;
      END IF;
    ELSE
      SELECT 'session expired' INTO in_msg;
    END IF;
    END
```

Comment: Your first select...why?....and the @affRow variable, what is the point?

Comment: the first select is for validation purpose wheather the email is present or not? And the @affRow is just for checking how many rows updated?

Comment: But the result of your stored procedure execution get stored on `in_msg`....and you are not using `@affRow` into any logical step on your sp!

Comment: the @affRow will be shown if the otp is varified if it isn't varified then in_msg will execute.

Comment: Are you using this stored procedure alone...or are you going to consume it from php, for example?

Comment: Anyway, your stored procedure needs refactoring...you need to improve the logic and the readability of your script.

Comment: No i am using this stored procedure with nodejs .Ok i will do the refactor thing that later but right now i have to solve this issue.

Comment: Good luck my friend ;)

Comment: Can you give me some solutions for this

Answer (score 0):

Fix timeouts by adding indexes and/or reformulating queries.

`mob_user` needs `INDEX(end_time)` and `INDEX(mac_id)`.

`SELECT COUNT(*), this, that ...` without a `GROUP BY` does not makes sense.  Nor will it work right with a `GROUP BY`.  What were you expecting??

`SET @checkEmailPresent=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table A WHERE email_id=emailID)` can be rewritten `SELECT @checkEmailPresent := COUNT(*) FROM table A WHERE email_id=emailID)`.  Note the `:=`.  That table needs `INDEX(email_id)`.

`IF(checkmatched=in_otp)THEN` does not make sense since `checkmatched` is nowhere set.  No that `SELECT` does not set it.

What is `ROW_COUNT()`?  I don't think it is a MySQL function.

Comment: I am using select COUNT to check wheather this mac id is present or not, and for that i dont need group by. We can also do SELECT @checkEmailPresent but if you look at the querie its getting multiple data from that same table and if i write select query for each data it will take more time.  ROW_COUNT IS THERE It will return how many rows are affected because of last queries.

Comment: You can probably combine the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` into `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, there by simplifying some of the logic.